# Moving Pace.JS On a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a sidebar that's 200px wide. I want my pace.js bar to load next to it. So basically have a margin of 200px to its left. This is what I've been using to edit it:

```
.pace-progress {
   background: #2dbaa6 !important;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 2000;
   height: 3px !important;
 }
```

I've tried multiple things.

- I tried setting the width with width: `calc(100% - 200px);`. That doesn't seem to work. I can only seem to set the width with `width: #px;` but I cant use that because my page has a fluid container.

  - for margin left I've tried `margin-left: 200px`, `left: 200px`, `left: 200`. None of these seem to work. And if they move it left, the bar loads in the opposite direction.
  - The only thing I can seem to do is set the `margin-top` element.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below will make `.pace-process` 200 pixel from the left and 0 pixel from the right.

```
.pace-progress {
   background: #2dbaa6 !important;
   position: fixed;
   left: 200px;
   right: 0;
   z-index: 2000;
   height: 3px !important;
 }
```

Comment: So, you're correct in that it move the bar 200px to the left. But now the bar move in the opposite direction. It start out full then gets smaller and smaller. Any idea why?

Comment: @MattThomas You need to post more code and preferable an example.